# php syntax coloring with HTML and jQuery

Tags: php, jquery, html

is it possible to have a `<textarea>` widget to support php syntax coloring with jQuery?

In short, I'd need to colorize code while the user is typing it into the `textarea`.

It would be great if line numbers were shown too, but it is not strictly necessary.

Any other framework would eventually be welcome.

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's a neat javascript library called [CodeMirror](http://codemirror.net/) that allows to do that.

There's the option to display line numbers, and works in real time, for a variety of languages, including PHP.

It is not related to and does not depend on jQuery.

Answer (score 0):

You can change the color of the textarea in the onchange with:

```
onchange="$(this).css('color','#00FF00')"
```